# Check html tag width size

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I'm working on PHP to output the email content. I want to check the width size through on the style of the html tag that if the width size which is greater than 400, I want to change it to 306px.

Example:

```
style="width: 406px;
```

If the width value is greater than 300, I want to change it to:

```
style="width: 306px;
```

Have is the html content on my php page:

```
<div class="a3V ui-widget-content ui-resizable ui-resizable-resizing" style="width: 406px; height: 128px;"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw a3T" id="nw" style="left: -5px; top: -5px; cursor: nw-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw a3T" id="sw" style="left: -5px; bottom: -5px; cursor: sw-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne a3T" id="ne" style="right: -5px; top: -5px; cursor: ne-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se a3T" id="se" style="right: -5px; bottom: -5px; cursor: se-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n a3b" id="n" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 1px; cursor: n-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s a3b" id="s" style="bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 1px; cursor: s-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w a3b" id="w" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 1px; cursor: w-resize;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e a3b" id="e" style="top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 1px; cursor: e-resize;"></div><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google" style="width: 406px;height: 128px;"></div>
```

Here is the code:

```
    $mailbox= $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM Drafts WHERE id = ?");
    $mailbox->execute([$id]);

    if ($mailbox->rowCount() > 0) {
       $row = $mailbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $draft_id = $row['email_id'];
       $draft_attached_files = $row['attached_files'];
       $draft_message = $row['message'];

       if (!empty($draft_message)) {
          $draft_message = base64_decode($draft_message);
       }


echo '<body>
        <div id="mobile-app-container" data-reactroot="" style="height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="app" data-test-id="mobile-app" class="a6" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="eM" role="message" style="display: block; overflow-y: auto;">
            <div id="eMB" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="mSG">';
                    echo $draft_message;

                    if (!empty($draft_attachments)) {
                        echo $draft_attachments;
                    }
            echo '</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>';
                echo "</html><body>";
```

I have got no idea how to check if the value is greater than 300, the only things I can think of would be like this:

```
if (strpos($draft_message, 'width:400px;') !== false) {
   $draft_message = str_replace('width:400px;', 'width: 335px;', $draft_message);
}
```

I would have to write hundred of lines for each different value which is not the right way to do.

Can you please show me an example how I can check on the tag for the width size that if the width size is greater than 400, then I want to replace it with 306??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps add this somewhere:

```
<style>
    div {
        max-width: 306px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I cant use it because the width size is in the variable `$draft_message`. Any idea how I can change the width size using the variable??

Comment: @chrisoojer i'm not sure you're understanding how CSS is processed in an HTML document. those inline styles should be overridden by what I suggested no matter where each are placed.

Comment: I do understand how CSS is processed in an HTML document, but I cant change the width size because the tag controlled the width size in the variable. If you look at my PHP code carefully you will see it. I tried to use `max-width: 306px !important;` using `<div class="mSG" style="max-width: 306px !important;">` but it wont resize the image. Any idea?

Comment: @chrisoojer the code i wrote puts a `max-size: 306px !important;` on every `div` in the entire document, not just that parent element that you are talking about.

Comment: @chrisoojer if you are trying to set the max size on an `img` tag, you just switch `div` in my code with `img`, or do both `div, img`.

Comment: Oh I didnt realised that you use div in the CSS. I can see it is working now so thank you very much for your help. Problem are now resolved.

Answer (score -1):

u can try and use max width set to 306px for that part

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).